# Is the Midgard Heroes Handbook Centaur race considered as Medium, or Large, for the purpose of grappling and shoving?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, racial-traits, centaur, kobold-press

In the "Midgard Heroes Handbook" from the Kobold Press, there is a playable character race, the Centaur (not to be confused with the somewhat different Centaur published in Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica & Mythic Odysseys of Theros !). Their size is rather unique - a Medium/Large hybrid, so to speak :

> Size. Centaurs stand between 8 and 9 feet tall and weigh in excess of 1,000 pounds. Your size is Large.

> Humanoid Torso. Although you are Large, you wield weapons and wear armor sized for a Medium creature, thanks to the proportions of your humanoid torso.

It is clear to me that, as a creature with a Large, equine lower part, a Midgard Centaur can be ridden by a Medium creature (provided they're wearing a saddle), but as a creature with a Medium, humanoid upper part, they cannot wield oversized weaponry.

**But what about grappling and shoving ?** Are they considered Large, or Medium for such things ? I can see an argument for either interpretation - since they're of Large category, but have Medium sized hands...

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Your size is large.

You are considered medium only for the things mentioned in the feature description and large for everything else. Hand size isn’t much of a concern for shoving or grappling when you weigh 1000+ pounds.

While [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/19862/62294) is about 3.5e, it does establish something of an in-universe precedent for a horse being able to grapple, so I imagine a centaur should have no trouble grappling at least better than a large horse.